# Using filters in Liquid tags

Tags: filter, tags, liquid, jekyll

I'm using jekyll and Liquid to generate a static web site on github pages.

I want to base some content decisions on whether the amount of content in a document has reached a specific number of works. jekyll has a liquid filter which counts the number of words which I want to use in an if tag. I've tried this:

```
{% if page.content | number_of_words > 200 %} 
    ...
{% endif %}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried to assign the result to a variable and use that, and capture the output from the filter. But so far I've had no luck.

Has anyone managed to use a filter in a liquid tag?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

EDIT: This is no longer the most current solution, see and upvote [Martin Wang's `assign`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20521867/312586) instead:

> ````
> {% assign val = page.content | number_of_words %}
> {% if val > 200 %}
>  ....
> {% endif %}
> >```
> ````

At the time this answer was originally written (2011) `assign` was not a viable solution since it did not work with filters. That feature was introduced one year later, [in 2012](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/History.md#240--2012-08-03).

Leaving my original 2011 answer below in case someone needs to deal with this problem in older versions of Liquid.

---

I don't think it's possible to use filters inside tags that way; it just doesn't seem possible.

However, I've managed to build a set of conditions that might solve your particular problem (discerning wether a page is longer or shorter than 200 words). This is it:

```
{% capture truncated_content %}{{ page.content | truncatewords: 200, '' }}{% endcapture %}

{% if page.content != truncated_content %}
  More than 200 words
{% else %}
  Less or equal to 200 words
{% endif %}
```

In order to make the calculations a little more precise, it might be wise to use the `strip_html` operator. That gives us:

```
{% capture text %}{{ page.content | strip_html }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture truncated_text %}{{ text | truncatewords: 200, '' }}{% endcapture %}

{% if text != truncated_text %}
  More than 200 words
{% else %}
  Less or equal to 200 words
{% endif %}
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks. Thats the best answer so far.

Comment: Works great for github hosting without plugins!

Answer (score 29):

```
{% assign val = page.content | number_of_words %}
{% if val > 200 %}
 ....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are being voted down. This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @HeShiming. This should be the answer.

Comment: This also worked for me while kikito's answer did not.

Comment: Seems like the only clean way to do it. Are there really no docs explaining that comparisons can't be combined with filters..?

Comment: Still (Nov 2017) the accurate answer. Above workaround works. And still no such thing like... `{% if (url | truncate: 6, '') == '/blog/' %}` (leading to always `true`, not always `false` btw. Just so you don't cheer too early :-))

Comment: The **correct** answer for sure. This should be accepted instead. `assign` is better than `capture` because `assign` keeps the number as a number while `capture` makes it a string. (Plus, the code is cleaner.)

Answer (score 1):

Just found https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Plugins which gives details on how to write a custom tag for Github. This looks like a possible direction to go as well as providing access to many other customisations from other developers.

Comment: I don't think those work for Github. They can be used elsewhere though.

Comment: Yeah, so I just found out :-( And after spending a couple of hours learning basic Ruby and coding up what I needed. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% capture number_of_words_in_page %}{{page.content | number_of_words}}{% endcapture %}
{% if number_of_words_in_page > 200 %} 
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Try this.

Comment: Nope :-) already tried that before posting. The problem is that capture produces a string variable which then doesn't work correctly in the if tag.

Comment: Oops! I had the exact same problem sometime back and I ended up using this. But now I remember checking it against a string.