# Use Liquid filter with Liquid Tag

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm having trouble combining a Liquid Tag and a Liquid filter/pipe.

Though I think this is a generic question and not related to the specific plugin, but in case it is relevant, I am using [jekyll-exiftag](https://github.com/benib/jekyll-exiftag).

---

The tag is: `{% exiftag date_time_digitized,{{image_dir}},{{image_name}} %}`. This command gives me the datetime that the given photo was taken. And it works. So the following code:

```
<p>{% exiftag date_time_digitized,{{image_dir}},{{image_name}} %}</p>
```

correctly produces this output: *2017-03-04 12:09:23 +0100*

---

I am trying to use the Liquid date filter to format the date.

To test, the following code:

```
<p>{{ '2013-11-29 00:00:00 -0500' | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}</p>
```

correctly produces this output: *November 29, 2013*

---

However, I'm not able to pipe the outputted datetime into the date filter.

I have tried two approaches:

Approach 1:

```
<p>{% exiftag date_time_digitized,{{image_dir}},{{image_name}} | date: '%B %d, %Y' %}</p>
```

Approach 2:

```
{% assign image_date = exiftag date_time_digitized,{{image_dir}},{{image_name}} %}
<p>{{ image_date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}</p>
```

Even the following, without the filter, has no output.

```
{% assign image_date = exiftag date_time_digitized,{{image_dir}},{{image_name}} %}
<p>{{ image_date }}</p>
```

---

I feel like this is a Liquid syntax issue, but I am having trouble figuring it out on my own. I would appreciate any insight into this problem!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using filters in Liquid tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972126/using-filters-in-liquid-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use [capture](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/variable-tags#capture) to do this:

```
{% capture image_date %}
  {% exiftag date_time,{{image_dir}},{{image_name}} %}
{% endcapture %}

<p>{{ image_date | date: '%-m/%-d/%y' }}</p>
```